# Why is $g(z)=f(z)-\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ analytic, if $f(z)$ is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

If a complex function $f(z)$ is analytic in some domain $D$, then why is the following function $g(z)$ also analytic in that same domain?

$$g(z)=f(z)-\overline{f(\;\overline{z}\;)}$$

My doubt arises from the fact that $\overline{z}$ is not analytic.

---

I've looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809145/proving-that-a-function-is-analytic-given-that-it-is-equal-to-the-complex-conjug) related question but it didn't help provide a clear answer.

Comment: Hint: if $f$ is analytic, then $f(z)$ can be expressed as a power series near each point of $D$. Can you express $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ using this power series?

Comment: This does not look right, just because $z \in D$ does not mean that $\bar{z} \in D$.

Comment: @copper.hat Hi Joe.  If we add the statement that $D$ is symmetric about the $x$-axis, and if $f$ is analytic on $D$, then $\overline{f(\bar z)}$ is analytic on $D$ also.

Comment: @MarkViola Hi Mark! Yep, just addressing question hygiene :-).

Comment: Relating your question to the question you say doesn't provide a clear answer, since sums and differences of analytic functions are analytic, it suffices to show that $\overline{f(\overline{z}))}$ is analytic, and a function is analytic if and only if it has complex derivatives.  The solution to the linked question is simply showing that the complex derivative (defined by a limit) actually exists.  Algebraically, what is going on is that $\overline{(\overline{z}^n)}=z^n$.  because complex conjugation is a ring automorphism. Now take limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(z)=f(z)-\overline{f(\;\overline{z}\;)}$
Then,
$\begin{equation}
\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{g(z+h)-g(z)}{h}
\end{equation}$

${=\displaystyle{{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{[{{f(z+h)-\overline{f(\;\overline{z+h}\;)}-f(z)+\overline{f(\;\overline{z}\;)}
}}] }{h}}}$

${{=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}\frac{[{f(z+h)-f(z)]-[\overline{f(\;\overline{z+h}\;)}-
\overline{f(\;\overline{z}\;)}]
} }{h}}}$

${=\displaystyle{\lim_{h \to 0}}[{\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}}-{\frac{\overline{f(\;\overline{z+h}\;)}-\overline{f(\;\overline{z}\;)}}{h}}]}$

${=\displaystyle{
f'(z)-
\lim_{h \to 0}}[{\frac{\overline{f(\;\overline{z+h}\;)}-\overline{f(\;\overline{z}\;)}}{h}}]}$
${=\displaystyle{
f'(z)-
\lim_{h \to 0}}{\frac{\overline{[{f(\;\overline{z+h}\;)}-{f(\;\overline{z}\;)}]}}{h}}}$

${=\displaystyle{
f'(z)-
\lim_{h \to 0}}[{\frac{\overline{{f(\;\overline{z+h}\;)}-{f(\;\overline{z}\;)}}}{\overline {h}}}]}$

${=\displaystyle{
f'(z)-
\overline{{ [\lim_{\overline {h} \to 0}}{\frac{{{f(\;{\overline z+\overline h}\;)}-{f(\;\overline{z}\;)}}}{\overline {h}}}]}}}$

$= f'(z)- \overline{f'(\overline z)}$

Hence, $ g'(z)=f'(z)- \overline{f'(\overline z)}$

[ Note :

1. $ f: z\to {\overline z}$ is continuous.
2. It is enough to prove $\overline{f(\;\overline{z}\;)}$ is Holomorphic.]

Answer (score 2):

You're correct.  $\bar z$ is not analytic.  But $\overline{\bar z}=z$ is analytic.

Suppose $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic for $z\in D$ and is symmetric about the $x$-axis.  Clearly, $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Then, we have

$$\overline {f(\bar z)}=u(x,-y)-iv(x,-y)=U(x,y)+iV(x,y)$$

Now show that $U$ and $V$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: See the coment by copper.hat

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I've modified the answer to add the assumption that $D$ is symmetric about the $x$ axis.

Comment: am trying to think this through - why does $D$ need to contain some segment of the real axis?

Comment: @tariq It does not need to contain a segment of the real axis.  I've removed that statement.